# teradata sql volatile table - case statement

Tags: case, teradata, volatile

```
Create volatile table sample as

(select a.orig_name , a.sample_date,

CASE when a.orig_name = 'Apl' THEN 'APPLE'
    when a.orig_name = 'Orng' THEN 'ORANGE'
else 'other'

end as orig_name_grp

from tablename_fr)

with data primary index(sample_date) 
on commit preserve rows;
```

this code is throwing me error in teradata , can anyone help me fixing what the issue
how to use CASE statement with condition on it`in volatile table`

case statement is throwing error in teradata in create volatile table

Comment: *throwing an error* is not helpful, what's the actual error message? If this is your actual code, it's the `sample` keyword, change the table name or double quote it: `"sample"`

Comment: this is sample code ,i cannot post my original code due to some restriction , error message is Failed [3706:42000] Syntax error :expected something between '=' and the end of the request   @dnoeth

Comment: You seem to use Studio, it will show the position of the error, there seems to be a `;` in a wrong place.